# Java и C# братья навек

Tags: предложение

Далеко не секрет, что два языка очень схожи. И часто вопрос и ответ заданные по одному, за исключением синтаксической мелочи, являются ответом и вопросом по другому. Только с точки зрения оптимизации поиска, можно каким-то способом помечать братские вопросы, как применимые для обоих языков?

Если нет, то как следует поступать когда видишь подобный вопрос-ответ?

---

Например, этот вопрос [Что правильнее Java Generic Interface и Generic Methods в данном случае?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748186/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-java-generic-interface-%D0%B8-generic-methods-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5)
Несмотря на упоминание вскользь специфичных классов, вообщем-то мог быть точно так же задан и отвечен, как вопрос c#.

Comment: а почему нельзя просто поставить 2 метки? Или метку `любой-язык`

Comment: Ставьте обе метки

Comment: @pavel любой-язык всё-таки для вопросов, которые вообще не затрагивают специфику языков. А я про общую специфику двух схожих языков. А две метки нельзя, так как автор задавал его для одного.

Comment: @pavel [tag:c#-или-java]

Comment: Хорошо бы видеть в сообщении ссылки на примеры таких вопросов, дабы не быть голословным.

Comment: @alexolut добавил тот, который попался сегодня и подтолкнул написать сюда.

Comment: @4per Если вы считаете, что подобный вопрос был бы актуален на C#, то никто не запрещает вам его же задать. И, возможно, самому и написать на него ответ. Но править текущий вопрос и подобные чужие, учитывая спефикой Java и с ответами на Java, в подавляющем большинстве случаев, считаю, что не стоит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Только с точки зрения оптимизации поиска, можно каким-то способом
>   помечать братские вопросы, как применимые для обоих языков?

Помечать **свои** вопросы, применимые для двух языков, метками обоих языков разумеется можно. Только вот круг вопросов, на которые можно дать одинаковый ответ и в C# и в Java, довольно узкий - в основном это теоретические вопросы и вопросы по базовым понятиям языка (и, скорее всего, на них должна быть метка [ооп](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%be%d0%bf) вместо метки конкретного языка).

> как следует поступать когда видишь подобный вопрос-ответ

Никак. Автор вопроса сам определяет, к каким языкам, технологиям и ОС он применим. Если вы хотите поделится решением для другого языка, задайте новый вопрос.

> Например, этот вопрос Что правильнее Java Generic Interface и Generic
>   Methods в данном случае?

Вопрос ни о чем имхо и вообще должен быть закрыт как "основан на мнениях" (если бы очередь закрытия не была переполнена и механизм закрытия не был так бесполезен). Так что не очень пример.